# Where am I wrong in epsilon-delta definition of continuity for $f(x, y) = x^2 / (x^2 + y^2)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, epsilon-delta

Let f be a scalar multivariate function :
\begin{equation}
   f(x,y) =
        \begin{cases}
            \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2} & \text{if } (x,y) \neq (0,0), \\
            0 & \text{if } (x,y)=(0,0).
        \end{cases}
\end{equation}

I need to find if $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$ or not. However, it seems not the case when looking at the $f(t,0)$ curve which isn't continous at $(0,0)$ but using the $\delta - \epsilon$ definition I find a valid $\delta$...
Can you see my error in this reasoning :

$f$ is continuous at $c=(0,0)$ if and only if :
$$\forall{\epsilon > 0}, \exists{\delta > 0} : ||(x,y) - (0,0)||<\delta \implies |f(x,y) - f(0,0)| <\epsilon$$
$$ \iff \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} < \delta \implies |\frac{x^2}{x^2 + y^2}| < \epsilon$$
$$ \iff \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} < \delta \implies \frac{|x|}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} < \sqrt{\epsilon}$$
But since $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} < \delta$, the ($x,y)$ point lies in a ball of radius $\delta$ centered at the origin. This clearly implies that $|x| < \delta$ thus we have $\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} < \delta$
So we just have to take $\delta = \sqrt{\epsilon}$ and the definition is guaranteed.

Comment: How does $|x| < \delta$ give  $\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} < \delta$?

Comment: Well if $\begin{cases}|x| < \delta \\ \sqrt{x^2+y^2} < \delta\end{cases}$ then $\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ should be less than $\delta$, innit ?
EDIT : Completely not, I missed that and that was my error, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error lies in the statement “This clearly implies that $|x|<\delta$ thus we have $\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}<\delta$”. That's not true. If, say $\delta=\frac34$, $x=\frac12$ and $y=0$, then both $|x|$ and $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ are smaller than $\delta$, but $\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=1>\delta$.

Comment: Yep, completely missed that, thanks !